# How to look for substring in a Freemarker array?

Tags: freemarker, contains, seq

I'm trying to read page's URL with `FreeMarker` and whether it has a specific word in it.

```ftl
<#assign
    my_page_urls = ["/foobar", "/foopub"]
    current_url = htmlUtil.escape(theme_display.getURLCurrent())
    is_my_page = my_page_urls?seq_contains(current_url)
/>
```

At the moment, it works correctly for the above URLs, but I'm having a hard time with finding the substring, as the above pages are meant to have url parameters after them. E.g. `/foobar?answer=true` won't work. I know `contains` by itself can find substrings, but I have an array of URLs and I'm wondering if there's any reasonable, non-looping way to do it :)

Comment: I ended up not needing the answer, but I'll leave the question on in case someone knows the answer and someone needs that later :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `?filter` with an arbitrarily complex predicate expression, combined with `?size != 0`:

```
is_my_page = my_page_urls?filter(it -> it?contains(current_url))?size != 0
```

Of course for URL matching that would be a rather naive check, and you would want a more complex predicate.

Note that above will stop processing at the first match, as FreeMarker recognizes use cases like `?filter(...)?size != 0`.